# Disabling Required Field Validators server-side of checkbox is checked

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have a Custom Control that has multiple textbox fields and a checkbox contained within it.

If the checkbox is checked, and the user submits the form, I need to allow them to continue if the textbox's are empty (and the checkbox is checked).

I have to implement this without javascript.

The problem is that on the OnInit event of the Custom Control, where I wire up the textboxes and their validators, I cannot access the value of the checkbox.

---

I have been trying to override the uniqueid of the checkbox so that in the custom controls's OnInit event I can disable the required fieldvalidators if this.Context.Request.Form["CheckboxId"] = "On", but as soon as I override the uniqueID of the checkbox viewstate stopped working.

The other thing I thought of is having a custom requiredfieldvalidator that takes the Checkbox in the constructor and is disabled if the value is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to perform the control initialization logic during the **Control.Load** event by overriding the **Control.OnLoad** method instead?
At that stage in the control lifecycle you should be able to access the value of the CheckBox.

As a side note, if you want to disable validation you don't necessarily have to disable all **Validator** controls. Instead you can simply set the **Button.CausesValidation** property to **False** on the button that will submit the form.

**UPDATE:**
It sounds like you are building a **User Control**, that is a complex control made up of an aggregate of simple controls working together as a unit.
If you want to do that entirely in code, like you would with a **Custom Control**, you should inherit from the [CompositeControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositecontrol.aspx) class. That gives you the best of both worlds. The child controls initialization is then made by overriding the [CreateChildControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx) method.

Comment: Do you have a link to an article that describes how to do that?  All the examples I've seen use OnInit to add controls in a custom control.

Comment: The Button is outside of the Custom Control that includes the validated controls - so that's not an option.   

Right now, I'm seeing the value of the Checkbox as being false no matter what in OnLoad

Comment: I haven't had a chance to see if this is a solution yet, but I will and tell you if this is correct, thank you.